# Wiring Dual Dimmer Switch

Tags: electrical, wiring, switch, dimmer-switch

I have a dual switch that controls my kitchen lights and my dining lights. It’s in a single pole location but has two switches, top and bottom, one for kitchen and one for dining lights.
Currently there are two hot wires (white) one to the top switch and one to the bottom switch.  And then two feed (black) wires, one from the top switch out to the kitchen lights and another from the bottom switch to the dining lights. Then there are three grounds that are twisted together with a single ground coming from those into the ground screw on the switch.

Now I want to swap that switch for a dual dimmer switch. Only problem is the wiring on the dual dimmer is different. It only has one incoming hot terminal, however the terminal has two options. A screw type connection and a push in connection. Can I put the two original hots together using one onto the screw and one into the push in connection?

(Edit-added)
New switch is Lutron Maestro.

The new switch is Lutron Maestro  MA-L3L3-WH   (Dual single-pole 300 W/300 W Dimmers)
Shown in the last photo is the box for the new switch.

First 3 photos are the original switch. I forgot to photo it before Unwiring but I marked up one of the below photos showing the original wiring.

[image]

[image]

[image]

The remaining photos are the new switch which I’ve already (tried to) wire except for the extra hot wire (white) which I’m not sure if I should just combine with the other hot or cap it off or something else…?

Thanks a lot!

[image]
[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Usually a screw and a push-in terminal ("backstab") are two methods of using _one_ connection point, and the backstab is _not_ recommended - they tend to come loose and cause shorts. If this is the case, the one switch will control both setts of lights at the same time. Please [edit] to include make/model of the new switch, as well as pictures of the current, undetached wiring on the old switch and a picture of the new switch.

Comment: @FreeMan thanks for the quick reply. I’ve added photos and more info. Let me know if you need to see anything else

Comment: @Robert can you post the make and model of the new dimmer please?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel The new switch is Lutron Maestro MA-L3L3-WH (Dual single-pole 300 W/300 W Dimmers)

Comment: @FreeMan l just created and added a mock-up showing the original wiring. Thanks so much for your help

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel I just added a mock up showing the original wiring. Appreciate your help

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't look like the MA-L3L3 supports your application

Answer (score 1):

### I think you'll need to replace the box with a bigger box

As far as I can tell, there are no dual dimmers on the market that support running the two dimmer sections off independent supplies, which is what needs to happen in your case (so that current is correctly balanced on the two old-style switch loops in your box).  So, you'll need to replace that box with a box that has one more gang in it so that you have room for two separate single gang dimmers of your choice.

Comment: I was afraid that was the case. Really appreciate your assistance. Thank you